# Making a random list in Scheme

Tags: list, random, scheme

I am just trying to randomly make a list and use it in a larger function.

```
        (define make-random-list
        (if
          (= (random 2) 0) (list 2 3)
                           (list 3 2)))
```

This only produces the list (2 3) and I am not sure why. What is happening to cause this?

I can make the function work if I write it like this

```
  (define make-random-list
   (lambda (x)
   (if
    (= (random x) 0) (list 2 3)
                     (list 3 2))))
```

and calling (make-random-list 2)

but I do not understand why that would work and the other one would not. What is going on with scheme that would not allow the first function to produce random results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first snippet, you're assigning the result of a one-time computation to a variable. What you need here is to define a function that will be evaluated every time it's invoked. Your second snippet does exactly that, but there is a shorter way to express the same:

```
(define (make-random-list x)
(if
  (= (random x) 0) (list 2 3)
                   (list 3 2)))
```

Note the difference in the syntax: a function definition encloses the function definition together with the formal argument names in parentheses, while there are no parentheses around the name of a variable.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference. If I call the first function 100 times it comes out with the same result every time, but if I call (random 2) 100 times it will not come out the same every time.

Comment: The first one doesn't define a function. That snippet computes one random list and stores it in a variable called `make-random-list`. The value of that variable stays the same no matter how many times you retrieve it.

Comment: Oh okay I understand now, so if I hit ctrl-r (run) and then run the code again it might have a different result because it is computed again? Right now all I am doing is having it display the first computation if I just keep entering in make-random-list?

Comment: Yes, I believe restarting your program can cause the value to change.

Comment: @AlexeyFeldgendler `defun` is for Common Lisp, this question was tagged as `scheme`, and there we use `define` for function definitions. Your answer to OP is incorrect.

Comment: Oops, indeed. I keep mixing up lisp flavors all the time. Edited the answer, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme, functions are defined by explicitly using a `lambda` like this:

```
(define square
  (lambda (x)
    (* x x)))
```

Or like this, which is shorthand for the previous syntax and implicitly is using a `lambda` under the hood - both flavors of procedure definition are completely equivalent:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))
```

The first version of your code wasn't working because this is just assigning the result of the evaluation of `if` to a variable called `make-random-list`:

```
(define make-random-list
  (if (= (random 2) 0)
      (list 2 3)
      (list 3 2)))
```

For defining a procedure in Scheme you have to use a `lambda`, either explicitly or implicitly. So your procedure should be defined using either of this equivalent forms:

```
(define make-random-list
  (lambda ()
    (if (= (random 2) 0)
        (list 2 3)
        (list 3 2)))

(define (make-random-list)
  (if (= (random 2) 0)
      (list 2 3)
      (list 3 2)))
```

Notice that you don't have to pass the `x` parameter if the only possible value is `2`, simply declare a procedure with no arguments.

Comment: Ah thanks, of course that makes sense. Just as a general coding rule if I am using this function specifically only in one other function should I define it internally into that or just with the rest of the functions?

Comment: @Jordan my rule of thumb for that is: if I use the same snippet of code in more than one place, pack it as a separate procedure. And if I'm using it only inside one  procedure, pack it as an internal definition inside that procedure - in that way, if at some point you discover that the procedure is useful elsewhere, it's easy to extract it outside