# How should i go about making rows in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am looking at making rows in a list. it needs to have 23 randomly generated numbers in said list, 6 numbers in each row, the last row only has 5 numbers, the last will be a user inputted number. 
ex.

`47 90 43 8 41 39
    97 18 36 35 64 45
    56 47 25 100 27 66
    97 45 18 57 8`

I have no idea how to do this, I can get it to print one row and I can add a number to that one row. but to make 4 separate rows I am just totally confused. I think its the fact that there are 4 rows? I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create random list of integers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172131/create-random-list-of-integers-in-python) ... or maybe [Making a random list in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555956/making-a-random-list-in-scheme) or maybe [Generating a list of random numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675242/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-in-java), who knows.

Comment: Please precise what is the language you're using, and more clarifications about your problem would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get it to print out one row of random numbers, you are almost there. The piece that you are missing is this: as you are running the loop that prints out the numbers, keep track of a counter (starting from 1). After each time a number is printed, check `counter % 6`. If the result is zero, print a newline. My Python is a bit rusty, and I don't want to write all your code for you, but something like this pseudocode:

```
get the user input number

start i at 1, increment i up to 23
    print a random number
    if i % 6 == 0 print a newline

print the user input number
```

Based on your question, you're probably already doing most of this, and just don't know how to determine when to start a new line. Hope this helps.